# OptimisticLockException - Sql Server - Handle

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, gridview, optimistic-locking

I am trying update a record in the database in one of the methods of GridViewControl. 
It is raising OptimisticLockException. In my database I have four date fields (dZadOpenDateTime, dZadCloseDateTime,dCreatedDateTime,dChangedDateTime) show in this picture http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/exception.jpg/

Can you give me some hint how to handle this exception.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table?

Comment: It is saving to database in other part of the code but it is raising an exception here. So, I guess there should not be any problem with sqlserver.